# Serial.read(): Value changes to ASCII when I input from Serial Monitor

Tags: serial

I was having some problems on a project, so to test my Arduino, I wrote the following program to check things. When I start the serial monitor, the value of `i` is 1, but after I start sending numbers, they change into ASCII. Why?

```cpp
int i = 1;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.println(i);
  if(Serial.available()){
    i = Serial.read();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you send the character `1`, `Serial.read()` returns the integer 49.
 `Serial.println(i)` then sends the characters `4`, `9`, carriage return and a newline.

If you want to get back the same characters that you sent, change the type of `i` to `char`.